# How can I effectively check if one word (in a list of words) exists in a string, in .NET?

Tags: .net

I have about 3 million rows of data I need to import. Each row has an address which is split into the following fields:

- street: eg. 1 smith street OR 2/4 smith street OR 1 smith st.
- suburb: richmond
- state:
- country: iso code.

When I read in each row, I need to match it against our own database, which has the same field structure.

Problem is when we have the following:

- DB: 1 smith st.  File: 1 smith street
- DB: 1 smith street.  File: 1 smith st.

I have a list of all the street abbreviations but I'm just not sure how to check for both types of street-types?

I'm trying to do this:

```
var addressIndexFull = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var addressIndexAbbrev = new Dictionary<string, int>();

File Rows:
- 1 smith st
- 2 smith street

DB
- 1 smith street | ID: 1234

Result:
AIF => "1 smith street" | 1234
AIA => "1 smith st" | 1234
```

(Note, the 2nd row from the file doesn't match at all. so it doesn't get added to either dictionary).

My gut feeling so far has been to do:

1. Search for an exact match.

   ```
   var addressKey = string.Format("street-suburb-state-country", ..)
                          .Trim()
                          .ToLowerInvariant();
   if (addressesFromDb["1 smith street-suburb-state-country"]) 
   { 
       //we have a match 
   }
   ```
2. Now search against the *opposite* street type..

   *No idea*

This gets me a large number of hits. But I'm trying to find more matches...

any thoughts?

NOTES: .NET 4.5 & C#.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am missing something

first normalize the read address - strip leading trailing spaces, strip embedded whitespace, normalize the number in the street address (no leading zeros,...), force to lower case. Make sure it matches DB as much as possible

try to match to DB

replace street by st, try again

replace street by st. try again

replace st by street, try again

...

this is normal heuristic matching

Sample code

```
//replace street by st, try again
var tryagain = addr.Replace(" street"," st");
```

probably better is to use table of regexs to look for things. Maybe somethign like this

```
var replaces = new List<Tuple<string,string>>{
Tuple.Create("\wst$", "street"),
Tuple.Create("\wstreet$", "st"),
Tuple.Create("\wroad$", "rd"),
};
```

then cycle through each one matching, replacing trying...

```
foreach(var reg in replaces)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(addr, reg.Item1);
    if(match.IsMatch())
    {
         match.Replace(addr, reg.Item2);
         if(lookup in DB) -> done;
    }
}
```

warning: the above is rough sketch code, that I am sure doesnt compile, google c# regex to get it 100% correct

Comment: Yep _ i was more after code examples as opposed to some higher level logic answer. Can you elaborate on how to do this: `replace street by st` with some code? I'm scared you might say: use a for loop. `for each abbriev, string.replace`.. this isn't that great when you have street types IN the street name ... eg. `Dark Alley Place`...

Comment: `match.Replace` won't work. It will match the entire line (yay) which means: this input string DOES match the pattern you gave. But then the replace will _replace-the-entire-input-string_ that was matched. :(